# How to read/write the first 128 bytes of a file C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, byte, filestream

I have a bunch of files with unwanted 128 byte headers. So I need to read/write the first 128 bytes to file A and the rest of the bytes to file B. Can someone help please?
Thanks.
PS. The file sizes vary from 100MB to 400GB

```
        private void SplitUnwantedHeader(string myFile)
    {
        int skipBytes = 128;
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(myFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            int bufferSize;
            checked
            {
                bufferSize = (int)(fs.Length - skipBytes);
            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            fs.Position = skipBytes;
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            fs.Position = skipBytes;
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143295(v=vs.110).aspx)  The read method has contains options you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following which works well. Also, included is a .NET 4.0 shortcut which uses the `CopyTo()` functionality.

Solution for .NET 3.5 and below:

```
private void SplitUnwantedHeader(string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
    {
        byte[] fByte = new byte[65534];                                                             //Declare 64k byte for read/write buffer
        long headerToSplit = 128;                                                                   //Declare the point where to start reading
        int bytesRead = 0;                                                                          //Declare total bytes read
        try
        {
            using (var fr = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))             //Open source file for reading
            using (var fw = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))     //Create and open destination file for writing
            {
                fr.Position = headerToSplit;                                                        //Set reading position of source file in bytes
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = fr.Read(fByte, 0, fByte.Length);                                    //Read 64k bytes from source file
                    fw.Write(fByte, 0, bytesRead);                                                  //Write 64k bytes to destination file
                } while (bytesRead != 0);                                                           //Loop until there is no more bytes to read
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);                                   //Catch exception (if any) and display to user
        }
    }
```

Solution for .NET 4.0 and above:

```
private void SplitUnwantedHeader(string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
    {
        long headerToSplit = 128;                                                                   //Declare the point where to start reading
        try
        {
            using (var fr = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))             //Open source file for reading
            using (var fw = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))     //Create and open destination file for writing
            {
                fr.Position = headerToSplit;                                                        //Set reading position of source file in bytes
                fr.CopyTo(fw, 65534);        //<-- Alternative for .NET 4.0
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);                                   //Catch exception (if any) and display to user
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream())
{
    stream.Write();
}
```

This stream provides an overload for the offset and count of the bytes that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SplitUnwantedHeader(string myFile)
{
    const int skipBytes = 128;
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(myFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        // Write the skipped bytes to file A
        using (FileStream skipBytesFS = File.Open("FileA.txt", FileMode.Create))
        {
            byte[] skipBytesBuffer = new byte[skipBytes];
            fs.Read(skipBytesBuffer, 0, skipBytes);
            skipBytesFS.Write(skipBytesBuffer, 0, skipBytes);
            skipBytesFS.Flush();
        }
        // Write the rest of the bytes to file B
        using (FileStream outputFS = File.Open("FileB.txt", FileMode.Create))
        {
            long length = fs.Length - skipBytes;
            for (long i = 0; i < length; i++)
                outputFS.WriteByte((byte)fs.ReadByte());
            outputFS.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that when writing everything but the skipped bytes to file B, it is possible to read the entire rest of the input file into a buffer and then write that buffer to file B. However, this would easily result in an `OutOfMemoryException` if your files really go up to sizes like 400GB. Thus, writing one byte at a time.